# Не удаляются элементы объекта

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Вася', age: '21', gender: 'male'}];

function fun () {
    var newArr = arr;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        for (var key in newArr[0]) {
            if (key !== arguments[i]) {
                delete newArr[0][key]
            }
        }
    }
    return  newArr

}

console.log(fun('name', 'age'))
```

Должно получиться вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения], но в итоге выводится массив с пустым объектом. В чем может быть проблема? Использование аргументов является обязательным условием.

Comment: `newArr`, кстати, тут вообще бесполезен: вы всё равно меняете исходный массив.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что каждый из аргументов сравнивается со всеми ключами объекта. И если хотя бы с одним из ключей аргумент не совпадает (а так оно и будет), то ключ удаляется из объекта.

Нужно проходить по ключам объекта и проверять, есть ли такой ключ среди аргументов:

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'Вася',
  age: '21',
  gender: 'male'
}];

function fun() {
  for (var key in arr[0]) {
    if (Array.prototype.indexOf.call(arguments, key) == -1) {
      delete arr[0][key];
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(fun('name', 'age'));
```

---

Так как меняется объект, являющийся первым элементом массив, то `newArr` я из кода убрал. Если нужно в итоге получать копию массива с копиями объектов, то можно это сделать как-то так:

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'Вася',
  age: '21',
  gender: 'male'
}];

function fun() {
  var newArr = arr.slice();
  for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
    newArr[i] = Object.assign({}, newArr[i]);
  for (var key in newArr[0]) {
    if (Array.prototype.indexOf.call(arguments, key) == -1) {
      delete newArr[0][key];
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(fun('name', 'age'));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое) Выручили:)

Comment: @AlexanderK на здоровье. Добавил вариант с копированием массива, если вдруг это нужно.

Comment: вызов slice не нужен, ты потом все равно идешь по этому массиву заново и копируешь каждый элемент

Comment: @Grundy это на случай, если меняться будут не только объекты внутри массива, но и сам массив (например, будут выбрасываться объекты из массива, если у них не осталось своих ключей). Вот в рамках этих фантазий (основанных на попытках автора скопировать массив присваиванием) я собрал пример.

Answer (score 4):

Первым циклом в пробегаете по аргументам, а вторым по полям объекта и сравниваете поле объекта с текущим аргументом. На первой итерации Вы удаляете из объекта все поля, кроме `name` (имя первого аргумента). На второй итерации удаляете из объекта все поля, кроме `age` (имя второго аргумента). Т.к. после первой итерации в объекте осталось одно поле, то на выходе Вы получаете пустой объект

Гораздо эффективнее и проще будет не удалять поля из существующего объекта, а конструировать новый

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Вася', age: '21', gender: 'male'}];

function fun() {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    var newObj = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < arguments.length; j++) {
      var fld = arguments[j];
      if (fld in obj)  // Проверяем есть ли у объекта такое поле
        newObj[fld] = obj[fld];
    }
    newArr.push(newObj);
  }
  return newArr;

}

console.log(fun('name', 'age'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Я просто оставлю это здесь

```js
const arr = [{name: 'Вася', age: '21', gender: 'male'}];

const fun = (...filter_params) => arr.map(obj => 
     Object.keys(obj).filter(key => filter_params.includes(key))
     .reduce((result, key) => (result[key] = obj[key], result), {})
);


console.log(fun('name', 'age'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Тоже положу, а то вы как-то очень сложно ее решаете

```js
var arr = {name: 'Вася', age: '21', gender: 'male'}

function getByKeys() {
  var newArr = {}
  for(var x in arguments)
    if(arguments[x] in this)
      newArr[arguments[x]] = this[arguments[x]]
  return newArr
}

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getByKeys', { value: getByKeys, enumerable: false })

console.log(arr.getByKeys('name', 'age'))
```